# When an image is added in HTML, other tags adjust accordingly

Tags: html, css, positioning

I am adding an image in HTML which is the title for the page. When I add it, it overlaps the rest of the content that comes after that. I need the rest of the content to adapt accordingly. Not sure how to do this.

My code looks like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="page_book"><div class="book_wrapper"><div class="book_content"> <!-- start description for page 1-->
                    <div class="title"><img src="img/soho_page1_image_0.png" alt="Introduction" width="30" height="50"></div>
                    <img src="pages/page_1.jpg" />
                    <p>This content.</p>

                    </p>
                </div></div></div><!-- end description for page 1-->
                <div class="meta">
                    <span class="num">1</span>
                </div>
                <div class="gradient"></div><div class="loader"></div>
            </div>
```

CSS:

```
.title
{
position:absolute;
left: 20px;
}

.page_book img {
    width: 70%;
    margin: 10px auto;
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.page_book p {
    line-height: 20px;
}
```

I tried removing the .title class but the image covers the whole width.

Comment: Your image is absolutely positioned, what did you expect was going to happen?

Comment: I tried removing the .title class but the image covers the whole width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
.title
{
    position:relative;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

Also, use

```
.title img{
    margin:0px;
    width:auto;
}
```

The image currently inherits the styles of `.page_book img` and that's what's causing all the mess..

Next time adding a jsFiddle to the question would be helpful

Comment: the image covers the whole width. how to control that?

Comment: didn't your specify `width="30" height="50"` for the img? how much of the width would you like it to cover?

Comment: that doesn't work.. not helping to resize the image to left of the div.

Comment: i want to resize as well as place to the left of the div.

Comment: use `.title img{margin:0px; width:auto;}` the image currently inherits the styles of `.page_book img` and that's what's causing all the mess